# Draggable Images

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have draggable images on my Windows Form.  The PNG's themselves have transparent backgrounds yet it only matches the panel's background color when I load it.  There are other labels with different colors I'd like to be able to see as I drag it instead.  Anyone know what to use to make this happen?

http://postimg.org/image/d8p4s53pf/

EDIT:

Trying to make the PictureBox truely transparant.  The drag stuff is done, but the background is just the background of the panel, and doesn't show controls it passes over.

I used this but it's a bit glitchy.

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle = 0x00000020; //WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        //do nothing
    }

    protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
    {
        RecreateHandle();
    }
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Do you want to know how to make your pngs transparents, or how to make your images draggable ?

Comment: Winforms transparency is a hack and it just takes the colour of whatever is behind it... If you post a link to the image itself, someone will be able to edit the image into your question which may make your question clearer

Comment: This will not work. For a chess board do consider setting the whole board in the Panels BackgroundImage (or Image) and Drawing the pieces onto the surface. Then you can either use __one__ PictureBox which is inside the Panel while you draw or, much more natural, simply update the position of the moving piece in the mousemove. For this you need to put the moving piece as the last piece in your list of pieces, so it is always drawn on top..

Comment: When the object is clicked it is brought to front.  Can a picturebox hold more than one image?  I've never done that, although now I'm sucking it up and learning WPF.  So far, its been horrible although I would like it to be supported graphically. I got the transparency to work but it flickers.  After hours of research, there is no way around it.  Win32 is not good with graphics.

Comment: A PictureBox has three independent levels: BackGroundImage, Image (zoomable) and surface where you paint on in the Paint event. (Good luck with WPF, I have given up on it 3 times already, but will try again. (But then I'm old..)) For the chess game winforms will do easily if you do it right, unless you want to animate the pieces and put glitz and shine on them. Databinding is also very nice in WPF, once you have learned it..

Comment: So in the picture box I can get away with just one and add a bunch of images?  Will I be able to drag them independently?  I'll do some research on my own, I never thought of that.

I am making headway in WPF...it is very different and I'm avoiding XAML at all costs.  I just don't know what they were thinking when they made stuff like this.  Seems 10x harder than win forms for no good reason.  And thank you for your help!

Comment: Sometimes (often) I think so myself. There were reasons but othing has yet forced me to go there.. - You can easily draw the 32 or so pieces in the paint event unsing a list of pieces with either bitmaps or rectangles that point into a piecemap/spritemap. I would not even bother with a control for the moving piece, simply mark it as moving in the list during the mousedown and draw it at the cursor in the mousemove. on mouseup try to put it on the new position, if it is legal..

Answer (score 1):

Dragable `Controls` as such are not hard in `WinForms`.  But once they need **transparency** the options are rather restricted: Each must be completely contained in its `Parent`; this implies that they all must be **nested**. No problem to create a set of transparent layers like you have in a graphics program.

But moving even **one** `PictureBox-Pawn` across a board full of others simply will not work with `WinForms Controls`.

But your aim is simple enough to do **without any** moving controls.

Instead you can simply draw the chess pieces onto the control surface in the `Paint` event. I have implemented a rudimentary solution and here is the `Paint` event from it:

```
List<ChessPiece> pieces = new List<ChessPiece>();
int mpIndex = -1;     // index of the moving piece
Rectangle mmr;        // rectangle where moving piece is drawn   

// board display variables
int pieceSize = 60; 
int tileSize = 80;    
int borderWidth = 50;

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(ChessPiece p in pieces)
    {
        if (!p.onBoard) continue;  // skip the piece?

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[p.pieceIndex], 
                             borderWidth + p.col * tileSize, 
                             borderWidth + p.row * tileSize);

    }
    // if we have a moving piece..
    if (mpIndex >= 0 && !pieces[mpIndex].onBoard)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[pieces[mpIndex].pieceIndex],
                             mmr.Location);
}
```

As you can see it really isn't very long. It makes use of a few obvious variables and a few less obvious ones. The `pieces` list and the `ImageList` must be prepared up front. The rectangle `mmr` is set in the `MouseMove`:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        mmr = new Rectangle(e.X - pieceSize / 2, 
                            e.Y - pieceSize / 2, pieceSize, pieceSize);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();  // trigger the painting
    }
}
```

I won't post the `MouseUp` and `-Down` events as they contain mostly code that doesn't actually pertain to moving transparent images but to managing the list of pieces..

The main idea is to draw all images from a list of pieces, unless a piece is not on the board. The moving piece is drawn separately, its coordinates are not from the board positions but from the mouse position.

If in the `MouseUp` event we find that the the move is illegal, we can simply set it back `onBoard` without changing the position and it will be drawn at its old place.

In the `MouseDown` we determine the piece clicked on, set its `onBoard=false` and set the moving index `mpIndex`.

The class for the pieces is not long or complicated either;

```
public class ChessPiece
{
    public bool onBoard { get; set; }    // is the piece standing on the board?
    public int row { get; set; }         // row
    public int col { get; set; }         // column
    public char piecetype { get; set; }  // a little simplistic..not used..
    public char color { get; set;}       // .. could be an enumeration!
    public int pieceIndex { get; set; }  // points into imageList with 12 images

    public ChessPiece(char color, char type, int r, int c, int ind)
    { onBoard = true; piecetype = type; this.color = color; 
      row = r; col = c; pieceIndex = ind; }

}
```

All in all the full code is around 180 lines, uncommented but including 60 lines of setting up the pieces alone and without any chess logic..

Here are the first 3 lines of the code to create the pieces:

```
void makePieces()
{
    ChessPiece
    p = new ChessPiece('W', 'R', 7, 0, 8); pieces.Add(p);
    p = new ChessPiece('W', 'N', 7, 1, 10); pieces.Add(p);
    p = new ChessPiece('W', 'B', 7, 2, 9); pieces.Add(p);
    ..
```

So, moving a transparent `Png` graphic over other `Png` graphics and a board image is rather simple..
Here is a screenshot that shows a black bishop over a white knight:

[image]

Comment: Very nice, very similar to what I have done already.  My drag function gets the mouse position, then continuously gets the new position.  

    x = x + (new - old);
    old = new;

on mouse up int cancels the background worker and then adjust the picturebox to the right square.

I do see how your method would be more advantageous considering it would need to document the original position in case of an invalid move.  I did get the transparency to work but it is flickering and has trouble updating fast enough.

Comment: Are you dragging a `PictureBox` now? As long as the unmoving pieces are not also ´Controls`, the dragging can work but as you see it is really not necessary to have any `Controls` at all. I use __only__ the `PictureBox`. The original position is not changed until the move is validated, as I wrote in my comments above. Of course it doesn't flicker at all. Are the other pieces also PictureBoxes??

Comment: I just remembered after posting that, I'm storing the location in the Tag.  if it's invalid it will find the original location in the tag.  Yea I have ChessPeice as a subclass of PictureBox.  Each peice is it's own picture box with the drag system built in (background method to find mouse movement and move it accordingly)